# Amadeus Self API search airport/city for Indonesian City not found data

Tags: laravel-7

In this case, i am search ***airport*** and ***city*** from indonesian country. But not have data from this API

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the test environment it's because the API contains data from Spain, United States, United Kingdom, India and Germany as you can see in the [data collection](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection). For access to full data you would have to move to production.